# React Js append div next to input if error

Tags: reactjs

I just started working with reactJs and i find it very confusing.

I have login with post and if user enters password it returns code 200. But what i dont understand is how can i append/add/show error next to an input (in Jquery that would be easy but here i just cant seem to figure it out).

So far i have

```
render: function() {

        <div>
             <label for="username">User:</label>
             <input type="text" ref='username' id='username' type='text'/>
             <label for="password">Password:</label>
             <input ref='password' id='password' type='password' errorMessage="Password is required"/>
             <a onClick={this.submit} className="btn btn-primary">Login</a>
       </div>
},

submit: function() {

       var username = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.username).value;
       var password = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.password).value;
       this.serverRequest = $jQuery.post(url, { username: username, password: password }, function (data,success,type) {

       if(type.status == 200){
          console.log('Good');
          this.props.func(); //this is from parent which changes state of login to true
       }
       else{
             console.log('Wrong password/username');

        //Show error next/under password input
       } 
      }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: you can solve this issues with `state`  like so https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49978/

Comment: @AlexanderT. i went with jzm answer. But thank you for the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `this.setState` for this. So when it errors, set a variable to be true/false.

e.g. After this line:

```
console.log('Wrong password/username');
```

add

```
this.setState({ error: true });
```

Then in your render() method, use a simple if statement

```
render: function() {
   var errorMsg;
   if (this.state.error)
     errorMsg = <span className="error-msg">Error</span>;

   return (
     <div>
       <label for="username">User:</label>
             <input type="text" ref='username' id='username' type='text'/>

             <label for="password">Password:</label>
             <input ref='password' id='password' type='password' errorMessage="Password is required"/>
             {errorMsg}
   // ....
   );
}
```

Comment: Just a question so i have to render whole child again but with errorMessage? if i understood this corectly? Still new to reactjs so im still confused about it

Comment: The virtual DOM gets diff'ed then the actual DOM only gets modified with the changes

Comment: Oh so thats the point, thank you. It Works i needed a "push in the right direction"

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a flag in the state and turn it on when the error comes

```
render: function() {

        return (<div>
             <label for="username">User:</label>
             <input type="text" ref='username' id='username' type='text'/>

             <label for="password">Password:</label>
             <input ref='password' id='password' type='password' errorMessage="Password is required"/>

             {this.state.errors ? <div >Errors </div> : null}
             <a onClick={this.submit} className="btn btn-primary">Login</a>

       </div>)
}


submit: function() {

var username = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.username).value;
var password = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.password).value;

this.serverRequest = $jQuery.post(url, { username: username, password: password }, function (data,success,type) {

  if(type.status == 200){
     console.log('Good');

      this.props.func(); //this is from parent which changes state of login to true
  }
  else{
    console.log('Wrong password/username');
        this.setState({
        errors: true
       });
        //Show error next/under an input
  }

}.bind(this));

}
```